# jquery auto expire div

Tags: php, jquery

I want to expire a div auto. I tried below code but it not successful. I used here php mysql and jquery.

```
<?php
require('dbconnection.php');
$output='';
$sql="select * from vacancy";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
?>

<div class="bs-calltoaction bs-calltoaction-primary" id="jobvacancydiv">
  <script>
    window.setInterval(function(){

      var current = new Date();
      var expiry = new Date("<?= $row['expdate'];?>");

      if(current.getTime()>expiry.getTime()){
        $('#jobvacancydiv').hide();
      }

    }, 5000);
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You can just store a expiration date in the database en check if the current date is > than the expiration date. if the current date is > than the expiration date. don't get the rows from the database.

Comment: You have missing `}` for if statement.

Comment: What php version are you using? Is your <?= supported? This shortcut has never worked for me. Only <?php echo (" html+script".$array."end of html");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), get milliseconds from the two dates and pass the milliseconds to setTimeout.

```js
function setToHappen(fn, d){
        var t = d.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
        return setTimeout(fn, t);
    }

    var date = new Date((Date.now() + 5000)); // hides div in 5 seconds
    function hideDiv() {
        $('#jobvacancydiv').hide();
    }
    setToHappen(hideDiv, date);
```

```css
#jobvacancydiv {
            width: 300px;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://www.indeed.co.za/s/7f3a41d/jobsearch_all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bs-calltoaction bs-calltoaction-primary" id="jobvacancydiv">
    <!-- Previously this variable was used to indicate job board jobs, we have replaced that with a more accurate source type check -->
    <a target="_blank" id="sja1" data-tn-element="jobTitle" class="jobtitle turnstileLink" href="https://www.indeed.co.za/pagead/clk?mo=r&amp;ad=-6NYlbfkN0AVIi8UxprrPGU7QPohOxOOpynq0pcPnEidcD-eE3H2SpG6EIh1TTe3r_vm_geuxhowjwjw1_DROQLSkBT5f6RmPYEBxfu-kjVY3ETKxFeVMdETck2VE1cZSQHPpUet3n1dea60qNLhRjTbp6XpWjBpqMSB56DhsFaThXNInZQDpRrcL0lxbSjSixrwKFZYP15M2ysDR0Wqa5HuFV3VfT_lOPS-ntupPndQ33gfftG6y7DEuym-M5UAxRGClw461Ci86d7VC0xQdpbSeEenHruXVpsGe2s6HVNyH_zFGzfWsTBgbYl3sppNrssiu80Fi_B-z4SWBV3-aZDbG766Afrg0OfDPPm4Cdnn_L18maYuyigcvyc41wgtytboVqyzyhvUJ6GqhRORUBdsxTKpyfOiY7zx-o0w101JRrUufW06cq6_tnaGT7JyFnh8E6q-PhSpGmhHXf9sI0lPrsFzEb8tMtzM0y9rHcfbk5M6Di_cdln7M3N3NKf5aY4I3UZ08kWsoNQqgJJPomPkB9L5DiVk7dBidgb9gFHRSYau-Fwx_MO2L2JrENDZKm6u_U55Ysja8afGYcOZ8R18u6AtxYNAGksnkHVmXnyUluCNouV8_RLF1Y89wWCpd0G54VfWVQu7j7Xd09ibqg==&amp;p=1&amp;sk=&amp;fvj=0&amp;tk=1bfesb4rj16re4ds&amp;jsa=4787" title="Marketing Manager (Email Marketing) - Johannesburg" rel="nofollow" onmousedown="sjomd('sja1'); clk('sja1');" onclick="setRefineByCookie([]); sjoc('sja1',0); convCtr('SJ', pingUrlsForGA)">Marketing Manager (Email Marketing) - Johannesburg</a>
    <br>
    <div class="sjcl">
<span class="company">
    <a data-tn-element="companyName" class="turnstileLink" target="_blank" href="/cmp/Uber" onmousedown="this.href = appendParamsOnce(this.href, 'from=SERP&amp;campaignid=serp-linkcompanyname&amp;fromjk=26490a5ccf6523e5&amp;jcid=f766f8bfbc3effb7')">
        Uber</a></span>

        - <a data-tn-element="reviewStars" data-tn-variant="cmplinktst2" class="turnstileLink slNoUnderline " href="/cmp/Uber/reviews" title="Uber reviews" onmousedown="this.href = appendParamsOnce(this.href, '?campaignid=cmplinktst2&amp;from=SERP&amp;jt=Marketing+Manager+%28Email+Marketing%29+-+Johannesburg&amp;fromjk=26490a5ccf6523e5&amp;jcid=f766f8bfbc3effb7');" target="_blank">
        <span class="ratings"><span class="rating" style="width:44.4px"><!-- --></span></span>
        <span class="slNoUnderline">130 reviews</span></a>
        - <span class="location">Johannesburg, Gauteng 2093</span>
    </div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td class="snip">
        <span class="summary">You should be a tested innovator and have excellent email skills, ready to launch Uber email campaigns that can match our rapidly growing global brand.What you...</span>
    </td></tr></tbody></table>
    <div class="sjCapt">
        <div class="result-link-bar-container">
            <div class="result-link-bar"><span class=" jasx_serpsjlabel_poststGray ">Sponsored</span> - <span id="tt_set_10" class="tt_set"><a id="sj_26490a5ccf6523e5" href="#" class="sl resultLink save-job-link " onclick="changeJobState('26490a5ccf6523e5', 'save', 'linkbar', true); return false;" title="Save this job to my.indeed">save job</a></span><div id="editsaved2_26490a5ccf6523e5" class="edit_note_content" style="display:none;"></div><script>window['sj_result_26490a5ccf6523e5'] = {"showSource": false, "source": "Uber", "loggedIn": false, "showMyJobsLinks": false,"undoAction": "unsave","jobKey": "26490a5ccf6523e5", "myIndeedAvailable": true, "tellAFriendEnabled": false, "showMoreActionsLink": false, "resultNumber": 10, "jobStateChangedToSaved": false, "searchState": "l=Boksburg%2C+Gauteng", "basicPermaLink": "https://www.indeed.co.za", "saveJobFailed": false, "removeJobFailed": false, "requestPending": false, "notesEnabled": false, "currentPage" : "serp", "mjwebtransgroupactive" : false, "sponsored" : true,"showSponsor" : true,"reportJobButtonEnabled": false, "showMyJobsHired": false, "showSaveForSponsored": true, "showJobAge": true};</script></div></div>
        <div class="tab-container">
            <div class="sign-in-container result-tab"></div>
            <div class="tellafriend-container result-tab email_job_content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```